# How to check if an email is already taken in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an API in NodeJS and MongoDB. The API in general just manages Students and Projects.
I need to add a new route to check if an email already has been taken in the DB. 
As param I need to pass the email from the body as `req.body.email` and then check if it is available. 
I tried 2 ways but nothing worked for me and not really know how to fix it.

The route I did in as first:

```
router.get("/check-email", async (req, res) => {
    await Student.emailCheck(req.body.email, (error, student) => {
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        }

        if (student) {
            res.status(401).json({ error: "Email already used" });
        } else {
            res.json({ message: "Email is available" });
        }
    });
});
```

and model:

```
const mongoose = require("../utilities/dbConnect");
require("mongoose-type-email");

const schema = {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    surname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    dateOfBirth: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
};

const collectionName = "student";
const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema(schema);
const Student = mongoose.model(collectionName, studentSchema);

const emailCheck = (email, cb) => {
    Student.findOne({ email: email }).exec((error, student) => {
        if (error) {
            return cb(error);
        }
        cb(null, student);
    });
};

module.exports = { Student, emailCheck };
```

Method 2 route:

```
await validateEmailAccessibility(req.body.email).then(
           valid => {
            if (valid) {
                res.send("Email is valid");
              } else {
                res.send("Email already used");
              }
           }
       );
```

and using a utility

```
let Student = require("../models/student.model");

const validateEmailAccessibility = async email => {
    const result = await Student.findOne({ email: email });
    return result !== null;
};

module.exports = validateEmailAccessibility;
```

I would like to understand the best way to achieve my goal and what I'm doing wrong in my ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on data type.

In your scheme definition, `email` field is typeof `mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email`. But, when you are searching inside Mongo, you pass `String` type.

**EDIT:**

Working code (used `app` instead of `Route`):

```
app.post("/check-email", function (req, res) {
    Student.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (error, result) => {

        if (result) {
            res.status(401).json({ error: "Email already used" });
        } else {
            res.json({ message: "Email is available" });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, becasue I'm using a PKG called mongoose-type-email to check the email is a valid format. Cannot be used a way around of it? or another way for it?

Comment: @Jakub, please check again

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting a response from another route ?? I see a student not found the message I assigned to another route:
```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    await Student.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(student =>
            res.json({
                message: "Student found!",
                data: student
            })
        )
        .catch(err =>
            res.status(404).json({
                message: "Student not found!",
                _id: req.params.id,
                error: err
            })
        );
});
```

Comment: If you can help me with one another thing is always saying the email is already taken also if the email is for real not present in the DB. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Let me check. I will use app instead of `Route`

Comment: Good job. i'm glad to help you

Comment: Yes but unfortunately still not work :( seems in nott validating I can pass whatever I want and always says email already taken so is not checking anything

Comment: Try to use method 2

Comment: I'm doing that but valid is always false so is saying email already taken I do not get what wrong